# How to query using mysqli prepared statements where 2 columns equal different values?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to query a database basically so it looks like this:

```
$stmt5 = $DBH->prepare("SELECT id FROM numbers WHERE value1 = ? value2 = ?");
$stmt5->bind_param("ss",$value1,$value2);
```

But i keep receiving "Call to a member function bind_param on non-object" how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an AND try this

```
$DBH->prepare("SELECT id FROM numbers WHERE value1 = ? AND value2 = ?")
```

Comment: thanks! i tried that first, but i recieved and error, but looks like it was probably a spelling or syntax error of somesort. thanks!